Blazor, session storage and deprecation reference library
While looking into implementing a simple session storage in a Blazor app, I found multiple references to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage and what appears to be some pretty simple implementations.  The problem is that this component is being shown as deprecated in nuget and I can't find a replacement.
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage
@inject ProtectedSessionStorage ProtectedSessionStore

What is the new/proper way of doing this in .Net 8 without the deprecated libraries?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/5.0/blazor-protectedbrowserstorage-moved - "In ASP.NET Core 5.0 RC2, a NuGet package reference is no longer needed to reference and use the feature"

stuartd, I saw this same article so I would assume it's available directly on .Net 8 but including that namespace in my project doesn't resolve anything.  I also include a few of the nuget packages as well for the 8.0.x series and nothing seems to resolve it.

It wouldn't be a Wasm app, would it?

To use ProtectedSessionStorage you don't need to install extra packages. The lastest Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage is already in the Framework Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.

So just use your code directly will be fine.
And I would recommand you to use Blazored.SessionStrage package to operate sessionstorage instead. It can be used in both WASM or Server rendermode. But ProtectedSessionStorage is only available in server project.
ProtectedBrowserStorage will automatically encrypt value while Blazored.SessionStrage do not. But it is not hard to implement encyption by yourself.
Reference: https://github.com/Blazored/SessionStorage

I ended up going with Blazored.SessionStorage for now.  It seemed simple enough for what I wanted to do.  I didn't think about the cookie encryption but that's easy enough.  It's an internal app with no PCI, and only limited PII.  It's good practice to secure it anyway, so that's next on my list.

I'm using Blazored.SessionStorage in my WASM Standalone app. I'm using session storage to store models info after calling my ASP Web API. I'm not sure if I should be worried about this info and if I should encrypted or not?
How to implement encryption? Does encryption something we should implement in WASM or its not worth it because all code (including encryption keys) can potentially be inspected by the user?
Is this NuGet package is supported and safe to use "NetcodeHub.Packages.Extensions.SessionStorage" ?
